# LayerDrawable programmatically

Tags: android, drawable, layerdrawable

Since my application's color theme is dynamic i can only create background drawables using colors and shapedrawables,
i want to build a edittext background drawable with colors and shapes as shown below.
But i want to do this programatically

How to build this same drawable programatically?

```
<item>
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="@android:color/yellow" />
    </shape>
</item>

<!-- main color -->
<item
    android:bottom="1dp"
    android:left="1dp"
    android:right="1dp">
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
    </shape>
</item>

<!-- draw another block to cut-off the left and right bars -->
<item android:bottom="10dp">
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

this is what i tried....

```
    GradientDrawable border = new GradientDrawable();
    border.setShape(GradientDrawable.RECTANGLE);
    border.setColor(Color.WHITE);

    GradientDrawable background = new GradientDrawable();
    background.setShape(GradientDrawable.RECTANGLE);
    background.setColor(Color.YELLOW);


    GradientDrawable clip = new GradientDrawable();
    clip.setShape(GradientDrawable.RECTANGLE);
    border.setColor(Color.WHITE);

    Drawable[] layers = {background, border, clip};
    LayerDrawable layerDrawable = new LayerDrawable(layers);

    layerDrawable.setLayerInset(0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    layerDrawable.setLayerInset(1, 1, 0, 1, 1);
    layerDrawable.setLayerInset(2, 0, 0, 0, 10);
```

but the result is different....please help....!

Comment: If your App-Theme is dynamic, why you don't use styles? http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html

Comment: I cannot keep values like colors in xml also... in my case color values are coming from server anyway thanks for your time... :)

Comment: Have you ever thought about using some images and applying a color filter on those images to implement the themes.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I finally got it working. Instead of using `GradientDrawable` I used `ShapeDrawable`.

By setting this `LayerDrawable` as an `EditText` background you can regenerate default `EditText` 
styles with custom colors.

```
ShapeDrawable border = new ShapeDrawable();
border.getPaint().setColor(Color.WHITE);

ShapeDrawable background = new ShapeDrawable();
background.getPaint().setColor(Color.BLACK);


ShapeDrawable clip = new ShapeDrawable();
clip.getPaint().setColor(Color.WHITE);

Drawable[] layers = {background, border, clip};
LayerDrawable layerDrawable = new LayerDrawable(layers);

layerDrawable.setLayerInset(0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
layerDrawable.setLayerInset(1, 1, 0, 1, 1);
layerDrawable.setLayerInset(2, 0, 0, 0, 10);
```

Comment: More explanation would have been better.

Comment: There is one thing you missed.
The `setLayerInset()` method accepts `px`, not `dp`.

Answer (score 0):

This also works with Gradient Drawables:

```
GradientDrawable border = new GradientDrawable();
border.setColor(Color.White);

GradientDrawable background = new GradientDrawable();
background.setColor(Color.Black);

GradientDrawable clip = new GradientDrawable();
clip.setColor(Color.White);

GradientDrawable[] layers = {background, border, clip};
LayerDrawable layerDrawable = new LayerDrawable(layers);

layerDrawable.setLayerInset(0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
layerDrawable.setLayerInset(1, 1, 0, 1, 1);
layerDrawable.setLayerInset(2, 0, 0, 0, 10);
```