# Using Drawable instead of shape

Tags: android, button, drawable, shapes

Is there any way to create a **XML drawable** with **drawable** and **stroke**?

Usually we use shape with stroke like this code:

```
        <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:angle="270.0"
                android:endColor="@color/rounded_container_bg"
                android:startColor="@color/rounded_container_bg" />

            <corners android:radius="11.0dip" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape>
            <stroke
                android:width="1.0px"
                android:color="@color/rounded_container_border" />
```

I think this is not possible to use drawable in this code But is there any other methods that I can use it to create an image surrounded by stroke?

I need this method to create buttons and I want to use a background image (PNG) with stroke.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use ImageButton instead of normal button

```
<ImageButton
    android:background="your_drawable_shape"
    android:src="your_image"
/>
```

or you can use [LayerDrawable](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#LayerList)

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/stroke_drawable"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/your_image" />
</layer-list>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer ...In the second method how its going to recognize the stroke from the image?

Comment: @user3051834 what do you mean "how it is going to recognize"? The shape is a Drawable.

Comment: @user3051834 You already made a stoke with shape, now you need to add another layer to top which is your image. That's the point of layerdrawable

Answer (score 1):

Use [LayerDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/LayerDrawable.html) (called [Layer-List](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#LayerList) in xml)

[LayerDrawable programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20120725/layerdrawable-programatically)

You can mix shapes from xml with drawable that are drawn in code and bitmaps and use it as single Drawable.