# Android - ResourceNotFoundException: File res/drawable/ratingbar_full.xml

Tags: android, android-layout, gradle, android-drawable, android-4.4-kitkat

Problem:

I have a XML that generate rating bar component. For styling the component, I have a custom styles that I put in styles.xml

---

styles.xml from Main

```
<style name="CategoryRatingBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.RatingBar">
    <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/category_rating_bar</item>
    <item name="android:minHeight">18dp</item>
    <item name="android:maxHeight">18dp</item>
</style>
```

styles.xml from Android SDK

```
 <style name="Widget.RatingBar">
    <item name="indeterminateOnly">false</item>
    <item name="progressDrawable">@drawable/ratingbar_full</item>
    <item name="indeterminateDrawable">@drawable/ratingbar_full</item>
    <item name="minHeight">57dip</item>
    <item name="maxHeight">57dip</item>
    <item name="thumb">@null</item>
    <item name="mirrorForRtl">true</item>
</style>
```

ratingbar_full.xml

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+android:id/background" android:drawable="@android:drawable/ratingbar_full_empty" />
    <item android:id="@+android:id/secondaryProgress" android:drawable="@android:drawable/ratingbar_full_empty" />
    <item android:id="@+android:id/progress" android:drawable="@android:drawable/ratingbar_full_filled" />
</layer-list>
```

I got intermittent issue especially for Samsung devices that run with Kitkat version (4.4.4)

The exception looks like this

```
    Fatal Exception: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #147: Error inflating class RatingBar
           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:720)
           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:762)
           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:771)
           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:499)
           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
           at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6493)
           at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5680)
           at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5563)
           at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5559)
           at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2229)
           at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1556)
           at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1516)
           at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:608)
           at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3693)
           at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:3109)
           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16749)
           at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.internalMeasureChildren(ConstraintLayout.java:1210)
           at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.onMeasure(ConstraintLayout.java:1550)
           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16749)
           at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5295)
           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16749)
           at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5295)
           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16749)
           at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5295)
           at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
           at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
           at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16749)
           at android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView.measureChildWithMargins(NestedScrollView.java:1446)
           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
           at android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView.onMeasure(NestedScrollView.java:512)
           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16749)
           at android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout.onMeasure(SwipeRefreshLayout.java:626)
           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16749)
           at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5295)
           at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:714)
           at android.support.design.widget.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:91)
           at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(AppBarLayout.java:1361)
           at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:784)
           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16749)
           at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:719)
           at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:455)
           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16749)
           at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:1060)
           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16749)
           at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5295)
           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
           at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:139)
           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16749)
           at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5295)
           at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
           at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
           at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16749)
           at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5295)
           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16749)
           at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5295)
           at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
           at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
           at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16749)
           at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5295)
           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
           at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2439)
           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16749)
           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2080)
           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1176)
           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1380)
           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1063)
           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5993)
           at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
           at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
           at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
           at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5584)
           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
           at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)

    Caused by android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/ratingbar_full.xml from drawable resource ID #0x108054f
           at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3451)
           at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:614)
           at android.widget.ProgressBar.(ProgressBar.java:322)
           at android.widget.ProgressBar.(ProgressBar.java:267)
           at android.widget.AbsSeekBar.(AbsSeekBar.java:69)
           at android.widget.RatingBar.(RatingBar.java:86)
           at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatRatingBar.(AppCompatRatingBar.java:47)
           at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatRatingBar.(AppCompatRatingBar.java:43)
           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:136)
           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1024)
           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1081)
           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:691)
           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:762)
           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:771)
           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:499)
           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
           at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6493)
           at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5680)
           at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5563)
           at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5559)
           at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2229)
           at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1556)
           at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1516)
           at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:608)
           at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3693)
           at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:3109)
           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16749)
           at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.internalMeasureChildren(ConstraintLayout.java:1210)
           at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.onMeasure(ConstraintLayout.java:1550)
           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16749)
           at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5295)
           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16749)
           at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5295)
           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16749)
           at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5295)
           at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
           at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
           at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16749)
           at android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView.measureChildWithMargins(NestedScrollView.java:1446)
           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
           at android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView.onMeasure(NestedScrollView.java:512)
           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16749)
           at android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout.onMeasure(SwipeRefreshLayout.java:626)
           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16749)
           at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5295)
           at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:714)
           at android.support.design.widget.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:91)
           at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(AppBarLayout.java:1361)
           at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:784)
           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16749)
           at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:719)
           at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:455)
           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16749)
           at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:1060)
           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16749)
           at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5295)
           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
           at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:139)
           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16749)
           at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5295)
           at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
           at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
           at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16749)
           at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5295)
           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16749)
           at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5295)
           at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
           at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
           at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16749)
           at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5295)
           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
           at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2439)
           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16749)
           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2080)
           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1176)
           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1380)
           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1063)
           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5993)
           at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
           at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
           at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
           at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5584)
           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
           at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)

    Caused by android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/ratingbar_full_empty.xml from drawable resource ID #0x1080550
           at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3451)
           at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:1894)
           at android.support.v7.widget.VectorEnabledTintResources.superGetDrawable(VectorEnabledTintResources.java:74)
           at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.onDrawableLoadedFromResources(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:435)
           at android.support.v7.widget.VectorEnabledTintResources.getDrawable(VectorEnabledTintResources.java:67)
           at android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable.inflate(LayerDrawable.java:159)
           at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:973)
           at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:913)
           at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3447)
           at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:614)
           at android.widget.ProgressBar.(ProgressBar.java:322)
           at android.widget.ProgressBar.(ProgressBar.java:267)
           at android.widget.AbsSeekBar.(AbsSeekBar.java:69)
           at android.widget.RatingBar.(RatingBar.java:86)
           at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatRatingBar.(AppCompatRatingBar.java:47)
           at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatRatingBar.(AppCompatRatingBar.java:43)
           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:136)
           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1024)
           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1081)
           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:691)
           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:762)
           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:771)
           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:499)
           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
           at
android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6493)
           at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5680)
           at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5563)
           at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5559)
           at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2229)
           at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1556)
           at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1516)
           at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:608)
           at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3693)
           at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:3109)
           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16749)
           at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.internalMeasureChildren(ConstraintLayout.java:1210)
           at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.onMeasure(ConstraintLayout.java:1550)
           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16749)
           at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5295)
           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16749)
           at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5295)
           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16749)
           at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5295)
           at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
           at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
           at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16749)
           at android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView.measureChildWithMargins(NestedScrollView.java:1446)
           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
           at android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView.onMeasure(NestedScrollView.java:512)
           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16749)
           at android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout.onMeasure(SwipeRefreshLayout.java:626)
           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16749)
           at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5295)
           at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:714)
           at android.support.design.widget.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:91)
           at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(AppBarLayout.java:1361)
           at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:784)
           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16749)
           at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:719)
           at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:455)
           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16749)
           at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:1060)
           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16749)
           at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5295)
           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
           at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:139)
           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16749)
           at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5295)
           at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
           at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
           at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16749)
           at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5295)
           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16749)
           at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5295)
           at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
           at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
           at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16749)
           at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5295)
           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
           at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2439)
           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16749)
           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2080)
           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1176)
           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1380)
           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1063)
           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5993)
           at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
           at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
           at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
           at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5584)
           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
           at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

Any thoughts how to solve this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Use `dp` instead of `dip` in your styles.xml. Also here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource

Comment: please provide your res/drawable/ratingbar_full_empty.xml

Answer (score 0):

If you are using vector drawables in your ratingbar_full_filled drawable then it will cause this crash.

Please refer [Vector Drawable in Layer List on Older Android Versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42885410/vector-drawable-in-layer-list-on-older-android-versions?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)