# Splash Screen triggers Resources$NotFoundException only on Android 8.1

Tags: android, android-resources, android-theme

I followed [this tutorial](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/splash-screens-the-right-way/) here step by step, it works fine on my API 21 emulator, but on my 27 it crashes as soon as the app loads with:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.myapp.myapp/com.myapp.myapp.ui.SplashScreenActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Drawable com.myapp.myapp:drawable/splash_screen_background with resource ID #0x7f0700a9

My file drawable/splash_screen_background is this one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:type="radial"
                android:gradientRadius="100%p"
                android:startColor="@color/primaryColor"
                android:endColor="@color/primaryDarkColor"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item>
        <bitmap
        android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_home_white_24dp"/>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

I tried to use `app:srcCompat`, pass the drawable directly to the `item` eliminating the `bitmap`, but the problem persists. I have seen some people saying to use `android:drawable=` instead, but they say this crashes on < API 21.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43601921/1227166) shows some pretty complicated extra configurations, including `gradle` options, I am not sure how this will impact my app, does it change the performance of vector graphics?

What's the right way to handle a `layer-list` on Android that will work on several APIs?

Comment: Wondering wherever you are applying this `layer-list` `splash_screen_background`, are you using `app:srcCompat` there? i.e `app:srcCompat="@drawable/splash_screen_background"`
?

Comment: I am applying it as a theme, as the linked tutorial shows

Comment: I am having the same exact issue. @mFeinstein did you ever solve/work around this?

Comment: No, I didn't :/

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out? I'm having the same issue all of a sudden.

Comment: Nope (14 more characters for stackoverflow to be happy)

Answer (score 1):

The tutorial [you linked](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/splash-screens-the-right-way/) posted updated steps to account for vector drawables

> The original blog post was created before vector resources were available on Android so all of the launcher icons are images, meaning no error is thrown by the  tag.
>
> Fixing this for apps with vector launcher icons requires deleting the  tag and moving the drawable and gravity attributes to the  tag.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:drawable="@color/gray"/>
    <item
        android:drawable="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:gravity="center"/>
</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

Like you have suggested in your comment, the solution to the problem is, that your resources are not in the drawable folder.

All your drawable resource files should be in "drawable" too. If you have special features for higher android versions, you can uploaded files in "drawable-v21", "drawable-v24", ...

I hope that will help, i had the same problem and after putting every resource from different drawable folder in the global drawable folder, my problem was solved.