# android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException in Emulator only on Android Studio 3.5

Tags: android, android-resources

My app has been running fine for months suddenly it fails to start in the emulator after updating Android Studio to 3.5. On my Pixel it runs just fine. What makes matters worse is that it works just fine on the emulator on my Mac running an older version of Android Studio 3.4. My Fedora 30 laptop running Android Studio 3.5 however wont run with the following crash.

```
08-24 21:06:32.846  1869  1917 W WindowManager: Token{a7beea8 ActivityRecord{ad906cb u0 my.comp.app/.login.LoginActivity t11}} failed creating starting window
08-24 21:06:32.846  1869  1917 W WindowManager: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Drawable my.comp.app:drawable/launcher_screen with resource ID #0x7f0800b7
08-24 21:06:32.846  1869  1917 W WindowManager: Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/launcher_screen.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f0800b7
08-24 21:06:32.846  1869  1917 W WindowManager:     at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:847)
08-24 21:06:32.846  1869  1917 W WindowManager:     at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawable(ResourcesImpl.java:631)
08-24 21:06:32.846  1869  1917 W WindowManager:     at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawableForDensity(Resources.java:888)
08-24 21:06:32.846  1869  1917 W WindowManager:     at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:827)
08-24 21:06:32.846  1869  1917 W WindowManager:     at android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:626)
08-24 21:06:32.846  1869  1917 W WindowManager:     at com.android.server.policy.PhoneWindowManager.addSplashScreen(PhoneWindowManager.java:3120)
08-24 21:06:32.846  1869  1917 W WindowManager:     at com.android.server.wm.SplashScreenStartingData.createStartingSurface(SplashScreenStartingData.java:56)
08-24 21:06:32.846  1869  1917 W WindowManager:     at com.android.server.wm.AppWindowContainerController$1.run(AppWindowContainerController.java:151)
08-24 21:06:32.846  1869  1917 W WindowManager:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
08-24 21:06:32.846  1869  1917 W WindowManager:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-24 21:06:32.846  1869  1917 W WindowManager:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
08-24 21:06:32.846  1869  1917 W WindowManager:     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)
08-24 21:06:32.846  1869  1917 W WindowManager:     at com.android.server.ServiceThread.run(ServiceThread.java:44)
08-24 21:06:32.846  1869  1917 W WindowManager: Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #7: <bitmap> requires a valid 'src' attribute
08-24 21:06:32.846  1869  1917 W WindowManager:     at android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.updateStateFromTypedArray(BitmapDrawable.java:849)
08-24 21:06:32.846  1869  1917 W WindowManager:     at android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.inflate(BitmapDrawable.java:770)
08-24 21:06:32.846  1869  1917 W WindowManager:     at android.graphics.drawable.DrawableInflater.inflateFromXmlForDensity(DrawableInflater.java:142)
08-24 21:06:32.846  1869  1917 W WindowManager:     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInnerForDensity(Drawable.java:1332)
08-24 21:06:32.846  1869  1917 W WindowManager:     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:1321)
08-24 21:06:32.846  1869  1917 W WindowManager:     at android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable.inflateLayers(LayerDrawable.java:279)
08-24 21:06:32.846  1869  1917 W WindowManager:     at android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable.inflate(LayerDrawable.java:194)
08-24 21:06:32.846  1869  1917 W WindowManager:     at android.graphics.drawable.DrawableInflater.inflateFromXmlForDensity(DrawableInflater.java:142)
08-24 21:06:32.846  1869  1917 W WindowManager:     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInnerForDensity(Drawable.java:1332)
08-24 21:06:32.846  1869  1917 W WindowManager:     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlForDensity(Drawable.java:1291)
08-24 21:06:32.846  1869  1917 W WindowManager:     at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:833)
08-24 21:06:32.846  1869  1917 W WindowManager:     ... 12 more
```

The drawable in question is located in the specified directory:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:opacity="opaque">
    <!-- The background color, preferably the same as your normal theme -->
    <item android:drawable="@color/colorPrimary" />
    <!-- Your product logo - 144dp color version of your app icon -->
    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/applogo" />
    </item>
```

And the applogo is also a XML in the same directory.

Any idea whats causing this? I seems to be the same issue as described here: [Splash Screen triggers Resources$NotFoundException only on Android 8.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52527811/splash-screen-triggers-resourcesnotfoundexception-only-on-android-8-1)

Comment: Is there anything unusual about `applogo`? Is it actually a bitmap?

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio try Build->Clean/rebuild project.

If this doesn't help than try:
File->Invalidate Cache/Restart

Comment: Didn't help :/ it runs fine on device but not in emulator.

Comment: Have You tried this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9788726/using-drawable-resources ?

Comment: Please see my revised question. I fired up my old Macbook, updated Android studio and checked out my source. It runs fine in the emulator there. I'm so confused right now.

Answer (score 0):

This is correct way:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/colorWhite" />
    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_splash" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Bu if it doesn't work, try this way:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/colorWhite" />
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_splash"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:width="200dp"
        android:height="60dp"/>
</layer-list>
```