# How to fix android.widget.TextView() requires api 21 error

Tags: android, textview

I have BubbleTextView which is a custom TextView with a blue bubble behind as background.

Here is my code:

```
class BubbleTextView(context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyleAttr: Int, defStyleRes: Int) : TextView(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes) {

    private val paint = Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG)
    private val rectPath = Path()
    private val trianglePath = Path()

    private val rectF = RectF()
    private val triangleSize = resources.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.triangle_size_20dp).toFloat()
    private val cornerRadius = resources.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.corner_radius_4dp).toFloat()

    constructor(context: Context?):this(context, null, 0, 0)
    constructor(context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?):this(context, attrs, 0, 0)
    constructor(context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyleAttr: Int):this(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, 0)

    init{
        paint.style = Paint.Style.FILL
        paint.color = Color.CYAN
    }

    override fun onLayout(changed: Boolean, left: Int, top: Int, right: Int, bottom: Int) {
        super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom)
        val myWidth = (right - left).toFloat()
        val myHeight = (bottom - top).toFloat()
        val centerX = myWidth / 2f
        val lowerEdgeY = myHeight * 0.8f

        rectF.set(0f, 0f, myWidth, lowerEdgeY)
        rectPath.addRoundRect(rectF,cornerRadius, cornerRadius, Path.Direction.CW )

        val delta = triangleSize * 0.5f
        trianglePath.moveTo(centerX - delta, lowerEdgeY)
        trianglePath.lineTo(centerX + delta, lowerEdgeY)
        trianglePath.lineTo(centerX, myHeight)
        trianglePath.close()
    }

    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas?) {
        canvas?.drawPath(rectPath, paint)
        canvas?.drawPath(trianglePath, paint)
        super.onDraw(canvas)
    }
}
```

`: TextView` is highlighted red with error: android.widget.TextView() requires api 21.

For api 21 and above the apl is working fine. But for below the app crashed instantly.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you should use the constructor, `public TextView (Context context, 
                AttributeSet attrs, 
                int defStyleAttr)`. Constructor `public TextView (Context context, 
                AttributeSet attrs, 
                int defStyleAttr, 
                int defStyleRes)` is only `Added in API level 21`. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView#TextView(android.content.Context,%20android.util.AttributeSet,%20int,%20int)

Comment: @PhilipBorbon how? Can u please edit my code and answer it below. Im still a newbie, the answer of the guy below did not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Constructor 
`class BubbleTextView(context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyleAttr: Int, defStyleRes: Int) : TextView(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes)` 
added in API level 21, so you only can use >= 21
[image]

You should:

```
class BubbleTextView : TextView {

    private val paint = Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG)
    private val rectPath = Path()
    private val trianglePath = Path()

    private val rectF = RectF()
    private val triangleSize = resources.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.triangle_size_20dp).toFloat()
    private val cornerRadius = resources.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.corner_radius_4dp).toFloat()

    constructor(context: Context?):super(context)
    constructor(context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?):super(context, attrs)
    constructor(context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyleAttr: Int):super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr)
    constructor(context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyleAttr: Int, defStyleRes: Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes)

    init{
        paint.style = Paint.Style.FILL
        paint.color = Color.CYAN
    }

    override fun onLayout(changed: Boolean, left: Int, top: Int, right: Int, bottom: Int) {
        super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom)
        val myWidth = (right - left).toFloat()
        val myHeight = (bottom - top).toFloat()
        val centerX = myWidth / 2f
        val lowerEdgeY = myHeight * 0.8f

        rectF.set(0f, 0f, myWidth, lowerEdgeY)
        rectPath.addRoundRect(rectF,cornerRadius, cornerRadius, Path.Direction.CW )

        val delta = triangleSize * 0.5f
        trianglePath.moveTo(centerX - delta, lowerEdgeY)
        trianglePath.lineTo(centerX + delta, lowerEdgeY)
        trianglePath.lineTo(centerX, myHeight)
        trianglePath.close()
    }

    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas?) {
        canvas?.drawPath(rectPath, paint)
        canvas?.drawPath(trianglePath, paint)
        super.onDraw(canvas)
    }
}
```

Comment: Super requires api level 21 in android.widget.TextView()

Answer (score 0):

The warning you are getting is from Android Studio Inspection which scans through all the Android API calls in the application and warns about any calls that are not available on all versions targeted by this application (according to its minimum SDK attribute in the manifest).

If you really want to use this API and don't need to support older devices just set the `minSdkVersion` in your `build.gradle` to 21 or higher.

Do note that `minSdkVersion` is An integer designating the minimum API Level required for the application to run. The Android system will prevent the user from installing the application if the system's API Level is lower than the value specified in this attribute.